# Is this simple C++ program using <locale> correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, locale

This code seemed to work ok in (ubuntu trusty) versions of gcc and clang, and in Win 7 on a VM via mingw... Recently I upgraded to Wily and builds made with clang crash consistently here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "The locale is '" << std::locale("").name() << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Sometimes its a gibberish string followed by `Aborted: Core dumped` and sometimes its `invalid free`.

```
$ ./a.out 
The locale is 'en_US.UTF-8QX�у�X�у����0�����P�����\�(��\�(��\�(��h��t�������������y���������ț�ԛ�������en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_UP����`�������������������������p�����������@��������������`�������������p��������������������@��@��@��`��������p������������0��P��p���qp��!en_US.UTF-8QЈ[�����\�(��\�(��\�(�����������@�� �����P�����0�����P�����\�(��\�(��\�(��Ȣ�Ԣ����������������(��4��@��L��en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8!�v[��������������@�� �����P�����0�����P�����\�(��\�(���(��h��t��������������������Ȥ�Ԥ�������en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8!��[�� ����[�������7����7��.,!!x�[��!��[��!�[��@�����������@�� �����P�����0�����P�����\�(��\�(��\�(��(��4��@��L��X��d��p��|������������n_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8ѻAborted (core dumped)

$ ./a.out 
The locale is 'en_US.UTF-8QX\%�QX\%�Q�G�0H��H�PI��I�\:|�Q\D|�Q\>|�QhK�tK��K��K��K��K��Q�K��K��K��K��K��K�en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8ѻ
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000b04a98 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

(Both program outputs above were abbreviated greatly or they would not fit in this question.)

I also got an [invalid free on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a05c98f8206ca178) with it as well.

But this is very similar to example code on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << "User-preferred locale setting is " << std::locale("").name().c_str() << '\n';
    // on startup, the global locale is the "C" locale
    std::wcout << 1000.01 << '\n';
    // replace the C++ global locale as well as the C locale with the user-preferred locale
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    // use the new global locale for future wide character output
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    // output the same number again
    std::wcout << 1000.01 << '\n';
}
```

Actually that code [crashes Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94d30d32ef961435) also... :facepalm:

[More](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443f20019b661ecd) [crashes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc5bc8edaa2007f5) of similar code from Coliru.

Is this a bug in the c++ library used by clang, or is this code defective?

Note also: These crashes seem to be restricted to the C++ api, if you use `<clocale>` instead things seem to work okay, so it may just be some trivial problem in the C++ bindings over this?

Variations using `setlocale`: [1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5d2c5d992a79b2) [2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53964c214bae870d) [3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c84d909cabec4eea)

Comment: Looks pretty obviously like a bug to me. Did you consider asking the clang mailing list and/or reporting it as a bug? Seems like a more appropriate place to ask...

Comment: If clang, the compiler, crashes compiling this code, then this is a clang bug, and should be reported.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah I guess that's the next step

Comment: Well, if `<clocale>` is used instead and the expression `setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)` is used, then it seems to work fine... so this is appears to be very inane and easily worked around.

Comment: On coliru, just `int main() { std::locale().name(); }` (with correct includes) gives the same free error

Comment: I guess the downvote rationale might be 'this is obviously a compiler bug' ; perhaps rephrase your question to ask whether or not this is a correct program

Comment: Yeah I guess at this point it is obviously a compiler bug, but I assumed I must have been doing something wrong, I mean it's hard to believe there is isn't a unit test like this somewhere. I was really surprised that it crashed on coliru. I will write a report I guess.

Comment: First, I see a little different between your code and cppreference code: try `std::locate("").name().c_str()` instead of `std::locate("").name()`; Second, I see your output, it seems that it never end, try it by adding a `null` at the end of `std::locate("").name()`

Comment: You could try stepping through the assembly in a debugger (the generated assembly by clang 3.7 looks [very simple](http://goo.gl/NBGhkI) altho IDK why it has stuff after the `retq`)

Comment: Looks like an issue to do with the ABI change in GCC's `basic_string`. `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` makes it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by libstdc++'s ABI change in its `basic_string`, which was needed for C++11 conformance. To manage this transition, GCC added the `abi_tag` attribute, which changes the mangled name of functions so that functions for the new and old ABI can be distinguished, even if the change wouldn't otherwise affect the mangled name (e.g. the return type of a function).

This code

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::locale().name();
}
```

on GCC [emits a call to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a4ed9f182ff972d) `_ZNKSt6locale4nameB5cxx11Ev`, which demangles to `std::locale::name[abi:cxx11]() const`, and returns a SSO string with the new ABI.

Clang, on other other hand, [doesn't support the `abi_tag` attribute](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529), and [emits a call to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/955539e4df4f7950) `_ZNKSt6locale4nameEv`, which demangles to simply `std::locale::name() const` - which is the version returning a COW string (the old ABI).

The net result is that the program ends up trying to use a COW string as an SSO string when compiled with Clang. Havoc ensues.

The obvious workaround is to force the old ABI via `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Comment: wow, that is some nice sleuthing! This fixes it on my machine and on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b08f590618a7398a, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c769ee07e51fb02

Answer (score 1):

I think the `""` parameter might be corrupting something. I don't think it's a legal argument?

To verify it's nothing else, try running this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::locale("").name();
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles and runs just fine with GCC:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic locale.cpp
  <= No errorrs, no warnings

./a.out
The locale is 'en_US.UTF-8'
  <= Expected output
```

ADDENDUM:

Exactly the same with MSVS 2013 - no errors or warnings compiling; no errors running:

locale.cpp =>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "The locale is '" << std::locale("").name() << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Output =>

```
locale
The locale is 'English_United States.1252'
```