# c++ libs from ubuntu 16.04 repo - compiler options

Tags: c++11, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with GCC 5.4 which does support c++11 and it is the default compiler. By default c++11 is not enabled in that particular version of GCC.

My intent is to use some of the binary libraries (not header only) from their repository (e.g. boost). In my projects I will enable c++ 11.

How were c++ libraries from the repository compiled? Is it possible to use them with c++ 11 enabled? I know that c++ libraries can be called from different languages (Java, Pythons, C# etc) by hiding all c++ stuff behind plain C interface. With boost it is not a case. If a certain function returns me a string or a vector or anything from STL then it is a problem. AFAIK STL objects binary representation depends on compiler flags (eg. std=c++11).

Thank you.

Comment: `g++ -v` will show you how it was compiled.

Comment: AFAIK you can call C++ library from C++11 and C++14 code even if the library isn't compiled with C++11.

Comment: C++ is mostly backwards compatible for this reason, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which exact libraries are you talking about?

If you are talking about the standard library, `libstdc++` is a part of `gcc`. It is always okay to link it no matter which standard you compile at. `gcc` also made a decision to include ABI tags, so that they can be ABI compatible with code compiled at C++11 and pre C++11. See for instance TC's really nice answer to a question I asked here:

[Is this simple C++ program using <locale> correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124994/is-this-simple-c-program-using-locale-correct)

If by

> How were c++ libraries from the repository compiled?

you mean, how are all of the C++ libraries in the ubuntu repositories compiled, the answer is, it may be different for each one.

For instance if you want to use `libfreetype6-dev` or `libsdl2-dev`, these are C libraries, they will be okay to link to no matter what standard you target.

If you want to use `libsilly-dev` from CEGUI, that is a C++ library, and it is usually best to use the exact same compiler for your project and the C++ lib that you are linking to. If it appears in ubuntu repository, you can assume it was built with the default `g++` version that ubuntu is shipping. If you need to use a different compiler, it's probably best to build the C++ lib yourself -- in general C++ is not ABI stable across different compilers, or even different versions of the same compiler.

If you want to use compiled `boost` libraries, it's probably best to use the libs they give you and use the compiler they give you. If you only use header-only boost, then the compiler doesn't matter since you don't actually have to link with something they built. So you then have more flexibility with respect to compilers.

Often, if you need to use C++ libraries, it's best to integrate their build system into yours so that it can be easily rebuilt from source and you only have to configure the compiler once. (At least in my experience.) This can save a lot of time when you decide to upgrade compilers later. If you use `cmake` then it's often feasible, but sometimes this can be hard, especially if you have a lot of C++ dependencies. If you don't use `cmake`, well, many libraries use `cmake` and it won't be that easy to integrate them this way. `cmake` is still kind of a pain anyways, so this might not be such a loss.

Comment: @quantum_well: I guess you should read T.C.'s answer in the other question pretty carefully. Basically, `clang` says, you are on your own. If you want to use `clang` you should compile all code at the same standard, and you shouldn't link to `boost` in your ubuntu repository -- you should compile it yourself afaik. As you say, if you get a `std::string` returned you are in trouble, even if you are just linking to `libstdc++`. In `gcc`, they have an ABI tag attribute, so C++98 std::string and C++11 std::string can coexist in same program.

Comment: If you are doing cross-platform development, i.e. you plan to use gcc, clang, mingw, I would recommend always compiling boost yourself, or using header-only boost only. Idk, maybe I'm a newbie, but this way I have a lot more confidence when I distribute code.